# PFSense virtual box installation broken

Tags: man-in-the-middle, virtualbox, pfsense

**steps to reproduce:**
Insert PFSense as iso.
Bootoad from iso in virtual box

**Expected:**
Install screen is loaded
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LX-Y-99zJ3M

**Actual:**
Screen with list command without install option is loaded

[image: pfsense command list]